# Is there a method built in spring MockMVC to get json content as Object?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, junit

In my Spring project i created some tests that check the controllers/ http-api. Is there a way to get the json content of response as de-serialized object?

In other project i used rest assured and there methods to acquire results directly as expected objects.

Here is an example:

```
    MvcResult result = rest.perform( get( "/api/byUser" ).param( "userName","test_user" ) )

            .andExpect( status().is( HttpStatus.OK.value() ) ).andReturn();
    String string = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

The method returns a specific type as json. how to convert this json back to an object to tests its contents? 
I know ways with jackson or with rest-assured but is there a way within spring/test/mockmvc

Like `getContentAs(Class)`

Comment: when you call your rets api, spring will automatically convert it to Object. you can specify which object it should convert to when calling. Cannot say more without any code snippets,

Comment: added example code.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As far as I know `MockHttpServletResponse` (Unlike RestTemplate) doesn't have any method which could convert returned JSON to a particular type.

So what you could do is use Jackson `ObjectMapper` to convert JSON string to a particular type

Something like this

```
String json = rt.getResponse().getContentAsString();
SomeClass someClass = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, SomeClass.class);
```

This will give you more control for you to assert different things.

Having said that, `MockMvc::perform` returns `ResultActions` which has a method `andExpect` which takes `ResultMatcher`. This has a lot of options to test the resulting json without converting it to an object.

For example

```
mvc.perform(  .....
                ......
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstname").value("john"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastname").value("doe"))
                .andReturn();
```

Comment: Although that works it creates a new instance of `ObjectMapper` which might differ from the configured one. You are probably better of injected the Spring Boot created one.

Comment: @Deinum, yes you r right. but this is just an example i showed. it is upto the OP how he wants to do. Still thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

This might be of use:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.togondo.config.database.MappingConfig;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultHandler;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
@Getter
public class CustomResponseHandler<T> implements ResultHandler {

private final Class<? extends Collection> collectionClass;
private T responseObject;
private String responseData;
private final Class<T> type;
private Map<String, String> headers;
private String contentType;

public CustomResponseHandler() {
    this.type = null;
    this.collectionClass = null;
}

public CustomResponseHandler(Class type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.collectionClass = null;
}

public CustomResponseHandler(Class type, Class<? extends Collection> collectionClass) {
    this.type = type;
    this.collectionClass = collectionClass;
}


protected <T> T responseToObject(MockHttpServletResponse response, Class<T> type) throws IOException {
    String json = getResponseAsContentsAsString(response);
    if (org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isEmpty(json)) {
        return null;
    }
    return MappingConfig.getObjectMapper().readValue(json, type);
}

protected <T> T responseToObjectCollection(MockHttpServletResponse response, Class<? extends Collection> collectionType, Class<T> collectionContents) throws IOException {
    String json = getResponseAsContentsAsString(response);
    if (org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isEmpty(json)) {
        return null;
    }
    ObjectMapper mapper = MappingConfig.getObjectMapper();
    JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(collectionType, collectionContents);
    return mapper.readValue(json, type);
}


protected String getResponseAsContentsAsString(MockHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String content = "";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getContentAsByteArray())));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        content += line;
    br.close();

    return content;
}

@Override
public void handle(MvcResult result) throws Exception {
    if( type != null ) {
        if (collectionClass != null) {
            responseObject = responseToObjectCollection(result.getResponse(), collectionClass, type);
        } else {
            responseObject = responseToObject(result.getResponse(), type);
        }
    }
    else {
        responseData = getResponseAsContentsAsString(result.getResponse());
    }

    headers = getHeaders(result);
    contentType = result.getResponse().getContentType();

    if (result.getResolvedException() != null) {
        log.error("Exception: {}", result.getResponse().getErrorMessage());
        log.error("Error: {}", result.getResolvedException());
    }
}

private Map<String, String> getHeaders(MvcResult result) {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    result.getResponse().getHeaderNames().forEach(
            header -> headers.put(header, result.getResponse().getHeader(header))
    );
    return headers;
}

public String getHeader(String headerName) {
    return headers.get(headerName);
}

public String getContentType() {
    return contentType;
}

}
```

And then use it in your tests like this:

```
CustomResponseHandler<MyObject> responseHandler = new CustomResponseHandler(MyObject.class);

mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/yourmom"))
            .andDo(responseHandler)
            .andExpect(status().isOk());


MyObject myObject = responseHandler.getResponseObject();
```

Or if you want to fetch collections:

```
CustomResponseHandler<Set<MyObject>> responseHandler = new CustomResponseHandler(MyObject.class, Set.class);
.
.
.
Set<MyObject> myObjectSet = responseHandler.getResponseObject();
```

Comment: the question is about "Spring" framework, that already has code that creates string responses and accepts string requests. the question is about how to use the same "code"/ logic in tests